# Multiple php versions - maximizing compatibility

Tags: php, moodle, multiple-versions

I'm hosting many moodle platform on a webserver.
They are mostly 2.4, therefore php 5.3.2 is installed.
For 2.5 it's needed php 5.3.3 (though if we upgrade from 2.4 to 2.5 it seems to work).
Some clients are wanting/demanding to have fresh installs of 2.5 and 2.6.
I know there are ways of having two versions of php running and have them active in different cpanel accounts.
So I want to have a legacy cpanel account, for older platforms, and another for current installs.
My main doubt is caused due to php 5.3.4 being lauched earlier this month: should this new cpanel have php 5.3.4 or 5.3.3?
Most websites we host are either joomla (which support a broad spectrum of php versions), html sites (with basic php) and moodle (crucial php settings).
This is not so much a technical question, but more on a pros and cons type of comparison.
Though there is loads of documentation and 'You should always use the latest up to date software.', I like to hear opinions and experiences from more experienced users and developers than me.

Comment: Can't you just go for the latest PHP version with all Moddles, Joomlas, ... ?

Comment: My worry is breaking older moodle installs.
While some clients want the latest moodle, other prefer the older ones because they don't want anything to change (they migrated from one e-learning platform to moodle last year, they don't want more issues from upgrading in the near future).

Comment: I know that you can easily setup different PHP versions using fpm/fcgi - http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-multiple-php-versions-php-fpm-and-fastcgi-with-ispconfig-3-ubuntu-12.10

Comment: As a developer, I'm regularly switching between Moodle 2.4 / 2.5 / 2.6 only my local computer, running PHP 5.5.9. I've never seen any compatibility problems (unlike, for example, running an old Moodle 1.9.3 site, which I had to work on the other day, that is not compatible with PHP 5.4+).

Answer (score 1):

Its not ideal but in 2.5 or 2.6 you could search and replace the check for PHP 5.3.x

eg: In install.php there is

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.3.3") < 0) {
```